# How to select elements of lists in a list group, if the elements(string) startswith a letter/number?

Tags: python, string, list, startswith

Here I want to select the elements in each list which meet the condition that they starts with '6'. However I didn't find the way to achieve it.

The lists are converted from a dataframe:

```
d = {'c1': ['64774', '60240', '60500', '19303', '38724', '11402'], 
     'c2': ['', '95868', '95867', '60271', '60502', '19125'],
     'c3':['','','','','95867','60500']} 
df= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

```
  c1     c2     c3
64774   
60240   95868
60500   95867
19303   60271
38724   60502   95867
11402   19125   60500
```

```
list = df.values.tolist()
list = str(list)
list

[['64774', '', ''],
 ['60240', '95868', ''],
 ['60500', '95867', ''],
 ['19303', '60271', ''],
 ['38724', '60502', '95867'],
 ['11402', '19125', '60500']]
```

**I tried the code like:**

```
[x for x in list if x.startswith('6')]
```

However it only returned '6' for elements meet the condition

```
['6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6']
```

**What I'm looking for is a group of lists like:**

```
"[['64774'], ['60240'], ['60500'], ['60271'], ['60502'], ['60500']]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `list = str(list)` you're converting your list to a string representation, i.e. `list` becomes

```py
"[['64774', '', ''], ['60240', '95868', ''], ['60500', '95867', ''], ['19303', '60271', ''], ['38724', '60502', '95867'], ['11402', '19125', '60500']]"
```

You then loop through the string with the list comprehension

```py
[x for x in list if x.startswith('6')]
```

Which produces each individual character in the string which means you just find all occurrences of `6` in the string, hence your result of

```py
['6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6']
```

Sidenote: Don't use variable names that shadow builtin functions, like `list`, `dict` and so on, it will almost definitely cause issues down the line.

I'm not sure if there is any specific reason to use a dataframe/pandas for your question. If not, you could simply use a list comprehension

```py
d = {
  'c1': ['64774', '60240', '60500', '19303', '38724', '11402'], 
  'c2': ['', '95868', '95867', '60271', '60502', '19125'],
  'c3':['','','','','95867','60500']
}

d2 = [[x] for v in d.values() for x in v if x.startswith('6')]
# d2: [['64774'], ['60240'], ['60500'], ['60271'], ['60502'], ['60500']]
```

Comment: Thanks for all the notes!!

Comment: You're welcome. If one of the answers here solved your problem, please mark it as the answer by clicking the grey checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert your list into str(list) since it is already string type.

```
lst = df.values.tolist()
lst = [[i] for l in lst for i in l if i.startswith('6') ]
print(lst)
```

Result:

```
[['64774'], ['60240'], ['60500'], ['60271'], ['60502'], ['60500']]
```

Comment: No need to convert array to list, you could just do `[[a] for arr in df.to_numpy() for a in arr if a.startswith('6')]` (using preferred [`to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) rather than `values`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
flatten = lambda l: [[item] for sublist in l for item in sublist]
print( flatten([ df[col][df[col].str.startswith("6") ].tolist() for col in df]))
```

Here, I used a list generator that collects all matching cells in a list, while iterating over the columns; this yields `[['64774', '60240', '60500'], ['60271', '60502'], ['60500']]`. To get to your desired output, I defined a function `flatten` which (somewhat) flattens that list to `[['64774'], ['60240'], ['60500'], ['60271'], ['60502'], ['60500']]`.